# How to optimize this nested for loop?

Tags: java, ms-access, optimization

I created a method that works Just Well Enough (takes ~4 seconds to complete) on my computer. However, the end user will use the method in a remote-desktop environment, where the same request took anything from 25-50 seconds to complete. How can I optimize this program?

```
private void compareAndPopulateArrays(List<String> listOfGenIdsFromXml,
        List<String> listOfGenIdsFromDB, String dburl)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    mdbAccessor = new MDBAccessor();
    for (int x = 0; x < listOfGenIdsFromXml.size(); x++) {
        Boolean matching_id_found = false;
        for (int y = 0; y < listOfGenIdsFromDB.size(); y++) {
            if (listOfGenIdsFromXml.get(x)
                    .equals(listOfGenIdsFromDB.get(y)) || equalsLanguageCodeIgnore(listOfGenIdsFromXml.get(x),listOfGenIdsFromDB.get(y))) {
                addNewMatchingRecognition(listOfGenIdsFromXml,
                        listOfGenIdsFromDB, dburl, x, y);
                matching_id_found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!(matching_id_found == true)) {
            newRecognitions.add(new NewRecognition(listOfGenIdsFromXml
                    .get(x)));
        }
    }
}
    private void addNewMatchingRecognition(List<String> listOfGenIdsFromXml,
        List<String> listOfGenIdsFromDB, String dburl, int x, int y)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String gen_id_Xml = listOfGenIdsFromXml.get(x);
    String gen_id_DB = listOfGenIdsFromDB.get(y);
    int issue_id = mdbAccessor.getIssueId(gen_id_DB, dburl);
    String issue_expression = mdbAccessor.getIssueExpression(gen_id_DB,
            dburl);
    String issue_detail = mdbAccessor.getIssueDetails(gen_id_DB, dburl);
    matchingRecognitions.add(new MatchingRecognition(gen_id_Xml, gen_id_DB,
            issue_id, issue_detail, issue_expression));
}
```

And all the mdbAccessor methods look similarly to the following:

```
public int getIssueId(String gen_id, String dburl) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    Connection connection = setupConnection(dburl);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement
            .executeQuery("SELECT issue_id FROM es_it WHERE gen_id='&&"
                    + gen_id + "' OR gen_id='&" + gen_id + "'");

    if (resultSet.next()){
        int getint = resultSet.getInt(1);
        resultSet.close();
        connection.close();
        return getint;
    }else{
        resultSet.close();
        connection.close();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

equalsLanguageCodeIgnore:

```
    public boolean equalsLanguageCodeIgnore(String gen_id, String gen_id_DB) {
    if (genIdsAreEqualMinusLanguageCode(gen_id, gen_id_DB)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean genIdsAreEqualMinusLanguageCode(String gen_id,
        String gen_id_DB) {
    return gen_id_DB.contains("P-XX-")
            && gen_id.substring(5).equals(gen_id_DB.substring(5));
}
```

New and improved MDBAccessor class:

```
public class MDBAccessor {
private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;

public void setupConnection(String dburl)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq="
                    + dburl);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
}

public void closeConnection() throws SQLException{
    connection.close();
}
////
public int getIssueId(String gen_id) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("SELECT issue_id FROM es_it WHERE gen_id='&&"
                        + gen_id + "' OR gen_id='&" + gen_id + "'");

        if (resultSet.next()){
            int getint = resultSet.getInt(1);
            resultSet.close();
            return getint;
        }else{
            resultSet.close();
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Emil can you tell what version of Java you're using, and how large the two lists you're iterating over are?

Comment: Also this code needs some real refactoring for readability.

Comment: what does equalsLanguageCodeIgnore method? show the code if possible

Comment: First make sure that the delay is really caused by your method. In remote desktop environments, it might as well be possible that your method completes within 4 seconds, but for some other reason it takes 50 seconds to show up on the user's screen. Try measuring the methods runtime (ie. through calling System.nanoTime() before and after the method) when executed via rdp and display the time. Then if you are sure ´this method is really the bottleneck, follow the advice given in the other poster's answers (especially the opening/closing issue mentioned by C. Ross seems promising).

Comment: @C. Ross: Java 1.6, they are about 500-1000 items large.

Comment: @wesoly: added the method to the bottom of the post!

Comment: @Axel: thanks for the tip! I'll try it out to be even more sure that this is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Get the items once, and pass the items around, instead of the lists and indexes.  This will limit the number of lookups done in the Lists, which I expect are quite large.  Depending on your version of Java you may want to use a [for-each](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) construct for readability.
2. I expect you could consolidate the database accesses into a single query, which would save time.

   int issue_id = mdbAccessor.getIssueId(gen_id_DB, dburl);
    String issue_expression = mdbAccessor.getIssueExpression(gen_id_DB,
               dburl);
    String issue_detail = mdbAccessor.getIssueDetails(gen_id_DB, dburl);
3. You seem to be opening and closing the DB for each query.  Open it once, and close it at the end of the function, as the open and close of the DB connection is costly (especially against Access IIRC).  You would likely want to make the connection object a member of your `MDBAccessor` class.  Remember to use a [try finally](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) construct to ensure it is closed.

---

Suggested refactoring for readability

```
private void compareAndPopulateArrays(List<String> xmlGenIds,
        List<String> dbGenIds, String dbUrl)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    //Better yet move it into an init method or the class constructor
    mdbAccessor = new MDBAccessor(dbUrl);
    for (String currXmlId : xmlGenIds) {
        Boolean matchingIdFound = false;
        for (String currDbId : dbGenIds) {
            if (currXmlId.equals(currDbId) || 
                    equalsLanguageCodeIgnore(currXmlId,currDbId)) {
                addNewMatchingRecognition(currDbId, currXmlId);
                matchingIdFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (!matchingIdFound) {
            newRecognitions.add(new NewRecognition(currDbId));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If someone could get the code to format in the list I'd appreciate it

Comment: @C. Ross Wish I knew... Forcing the code formatting using backticks resets the list counter (3. becomes 1.) :(

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply! Will try this out today when I have some time.

Comment: I did the refactoring and it is much more readable now, and it shaved off some processingtime aswell, thanks for that. As for part 3) , I think I have some reading to do. Could you be so kind and tell me if this (http://blog.shinetech.com/?p=66) seems to be a proper reasource for the matter?

Comment: I did as you explained, added the connection and statement as members of the class, initialized them in an init() method and closed the connection in a closeConnection() method that I placed at the end of the function. This shaved the processingtime from 25s to ~2s ! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: As you can see from the updated "new and improved" MDBAccessor class, I still haven't used a try finally to close it "properly". I read the blogpost describing this, but I still haven't completely grasped the concept and have to apply it to my scenario. Since I open the connection in a method, and use it several times before closing it at the end of my comparemethod, how could I make sure it closes "every time" properly?

Comment: @Emil a [finalizer](http://java.sys-con.com/node/995699) would probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could try make some short of hash map from listOfGenIdsFromDB and replace the inner loop with map look ups, this would reduce need to repeatedly iterate over listOfGenIdsFromDB.

Comment: You might want to note that they will probably have to implement a custom comparer (to handle the `equalsLanguageCodeIgnore`).  Not to be snobbish, but I think that may be a little beyond the user's knowledge.

Comment: Everything depends on equalsLanguageCodeIgnore method implementation. If only what does this method is generating single value for each parameter and comparing them its possible to maintain additional map for these values. This leads to replacing inner loop with two maps.

Comment: True, and he hasn't been forthcoming with additional information.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. I had this idea aswell, and although C. Ross is correct that I don't have that much experience, I think it could be done quite easily as you'll see that the equalsLanguageCodeIgnore method (added at the bottom of the original post) is very straightforward. Will check this out later aswell!

Comment: I suppose making this change would shave even more off the processing time? Will def look into it when I have the time. Thanks alot.